# Strange Webkit Issue in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, webkit, woothemes

Large amounts of white-space in the body of this page - something is setting height: 4148.21875px; but cant find what.

http://wp.ewsproduction.com/backtohealth/

Wordpress site using woothemes.

Fonts don't render until developer tools are opened.

Site only behaves this way in webkit (tested in chrome, safari)

We can't seem to find the issue.

Any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I found the source of the issue  with the fonts not loading until inspector is opened:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

Answer (score 1):

I found one line at 2159 in style.css.

**.widget_woothemes_features .features .feature .feature-content { overflow: hidden;  }**

It gives to feature block some 3000px height.
If I remove this rule evething is perfect!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats amazing.. can I ask.. How did you find that?

Comment: Hi, you welcome! Just use Chrome inspect element and try few divs to disable styling and found it. Cheers!